# Opening a fragment from fragment by a button click

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 2 fragments Mainfragment have btn_a. I want to click that button and go to the Twofragment.

I implemented this but not working. Please help me.

Following code is in the `onCreateView` method of Main fragment,

```
ImageButton btn_a = (ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.aButton);
        btn_a.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TwoFragment two = new TwoFragment();
                getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.aFragment, two, "fragment");

            }
        });
```

**EDIT :**
I added `.commit();`. now shows another error as below
`no view found for id 0x7f09009b for fragment`help me on this.

**EDIT 2**
my xml file code is shown below

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/afragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/aListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you forget to call **commit**

Comment: make sure that you are using the correct fragment container id

Comment: @Alexander Thanks yes I missed that. now shows  new error please help me on that.

Comment: @tenten I think the problem is in the activity layout. By the way do you try search the answer? There are many answers on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Alexander i searched but nothing worked for me yet

Comment: can you share your xml ?

Comment: @WannaBeGeek check my edit

Comment: sometime fragment open as transparent.set background color in your fragment layout.

Comment: Is the fragment you trying to open a nested fragment?

Comment: @WannaBeGeek it is a fragment for getting database content to the list view

Comment: Is the xml that you posted was that of Mainfragment 's?

Comment: @WannaBeGeek its Twofragment's

Comment: can you post Mainfragment's  xml ?

Comment: error is you have R.id.aFragment inside your twoFragment where as you are using it inside MainFragment . so , its unable to find . Assign id to Mainfragment layout and then try to replace it. Also not forgot to use the childfragmentmanager instead of fragment manager .

Answer (score 3):

Try like this

```
getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.aFragment, two, "fragment").commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
SecondFragment secFrag = new SecondFragment();
FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_fragment,secFrag );
fragTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragTransaction.commit();
```